# how can write below changeValue function shortly?

Tags: java, function, logic

below code is written from **java**. i need to change the variable value dynamically by function. how can we write below **changeValue function** shortly? is there any way to pass the variables reference to function?

```
public class Project{
    private int value1;
    private int value2;
    private int value3;
    private int value4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        this.changeValue("value1",10)
        this.changeValue("value2",25)
        this.changeValue("value3",30)
        this.changeValue("value4",40)
    }

    public String changeValue(String varName,String value){
        if(varName=="value1"){
            this.value1=value
        }else if(varName=="value2"){
            this.value2=value
        }else if(varName=="value3"){
            this.value3=value
        }else if(varName=="value3"){
            this.value4=value
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not a good practice. you need to use  .equals() while comparing Strings.

Comment: Thank you. I agree @Shaik Bajivali. but i need some explanation about your answer. equals() function also have the same logic inside. then why we use the equals() method for compare two strings?

Comment: go though this simplest example to understand the difference.       https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/

Comment: ✔ Thank you @Shaik Bajivali

Answer (score 1):

Your code, as posted, contains many errors; for example, you can't store a `String` in an `int` - `String value` should be `int value`. You can't invoke instance methods from a `static` context with `this` in `main`, etc. However, to your question, **yes** you can make `changeValue` shorter, store your values in an array. Also, `changeValue` doesn't return a `String` - but if you make it return a `Project` you can chain your calls to `changeValue()`. Like,

```
private int[] values = new int[4];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Project p = new Project();
    p.changeValue("value1", 10).changeValue("value2", 25)
            .changeValue("value3", 30).changeValue("value4", 40);
    System.out.println(p);
}

public Project changeValue(String varName, int value) {
    int i = Character.digit(varName.charAt(varName.length() - 1), 10) - 1;
    values[i] = value;
    return this;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return Arrays.toString(values);
}
```

See also the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Java).

Comment: ya its is correct. but actually my code made for validate some UI input from fxml & java. **each variable name is mapped to UI labels.** when we change a variable value  then the UI label text value changing automatically. you can skip that string, int type errors and parameter errors. if there any way to reduce only the changeValue function, let me know. thank you

Comment: I have posted a `changeValue` function with three lines of code; your original version was nine lines. I'm not sure how much shorter you think it can be; beyond that your comment makes little sense in light of the code you have actually posted. Consider editing your question to add more context.

Comment: ya you are absolutely correct @Elliott Frisch. your code is correct when we use array variable. but i do not need  int[] array variable. i need multiple variables without array, but one (changeValue)function.

Comment: You need something to store the variables; an array or a Map are what exist. You can load the values from an external source. Best of luck!